# Is it necessary to declare status in express response?

Tags: node.js, express

I saw many usages below in express applications:

```
res.send(...)
```

Isn't it necessary to declare response status?

```
res.status(200).send(...)
```

Which is correct?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status)? If you don't set it, it's `200` by default.

Comment: But it is not required, express set 200 as default. But what if you need to return 400 because of a bad body? The good practice is to match the status code to the case:
https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html